# How to get the datastorage device type(ssd or no-ssd) with pythere

Tags: python, vmware

I want to get the datastorage device type is ssd or no-ssd and distinguish the datastorage is local SCSI disk or iSCSI device. My requirement is clone vm on ssd or clone vm on iSCSI device.

The code can get device type and datastore name, but I can not connect them.

```
from pysphere import VIServer, VIProperty 

server = VIServer()
server.connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD) 

for ds_mor, name in server.get_hosts().items(): 
    props = VIProperty(server, ds_mor) 
    for item in props.config.storageDevice.scsiLun:
        print item.displayName
        print "----------------------1"
    for item4 in props.datastore :
        print item4.info.url
        print item4.info.name
        print "----------------------2"
server.disconnect()
```

Result:

```
Local SMC Disk (naa.600304800cf26f001a1e6f391c22755f)
----------------------1
VIOLIN iSCSI Disk (naa.6001b970d8b7afa7d8b7afa78a0e63cc)
----------------------1
Local SMC Disk (naa.600304800cf26f001a1e6f391c22aec8)
----------------------1
/vmfs/volumes/532733bb-cb47ac13-a978-0025908c2110
ds-violin-1tb
----------------------2
/vmfs/volumes/52912281-5393bb5e-4cb5-0025908ac4e8
d11-4
----------------------2
/vmfs/volumes/528bb73c-d8b90c36-4bd6-0025908ac4e8
datastore11
----------------------2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to look in the array of disk info stored in props.config.storageDevice._obj.ScsiLun. This is what I was able to come up with when I was playing around with the objects in the bpython interpreter:

```
>>> for lun in props.config.storageDevice._obj.ScsiLun:
...     print "%s, %s" % ( lun.Model, lun.Vendor )
...     
... 
VMware IDE CDR10, NECVMWar
Virtual disk, VMware
TierStore, NexGen
Virtual disk, VMware
>>>
```

I don't know if this will get you most of what you want, there is another alternative location to look for iSCSI information, and that's under props.configManager.storageSystem.multipathStateInfo._obj.Path.  When looking there, you can find the IQN->naa.* mappings, and use that to see what drives are provided by iSCSI, and cross correlate that with your drive info above.

```
>>> for path in props.configManager.storageSystem.multipathStateInfo._obj.Path:
...     path.Name
...     
... 
'ide.vmhba32-ide.0:0-mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0'
'iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:tml-esx-1-0e009bbe-00023d000001,iqn.2010-11.com.nexgenstorage:esxHostTest:c17c704c-0031a7cc-7c90-c77662adf00d,t,1-naa.6f49461701dba1a92c284fbd6fa32d7e'
'iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:tml-esx-1-0e009bbe-00023d000002,iqn.2010-11.com.nexgenstorage:esxHostTest:c17c704c-0031a7cc-7c90-c77662adf00d,t,2-naa.6f49461701dba1a92c284fbd6fa32d7e'
'iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:tml-esx-1-0e009bbe-00023d000003,iqn.2010-11.com.nexgenstorage:esxHostTest:c17c704c-0031a7cc-7c90-c77662adf00d,t,2-naa.6f49461701dba1a92c284fbd6fa32d7e'
'iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:tml-esx-1-0e009bbe-00023d000004,iqn.2010-11.com.nexgenstorage:esxHostTest:c17c704c-0031a7cc-7c90-c77662adf00d,t,1-naa.6f49461701dba1a92c284fbd6fa32d7e'
'pscsi.vmhba1-pscsi.0:0-mpx.vmhba1:C0:T0:L0'
'pscsi.vmhba1-pscsi.0:1-mpx.vmhba1:C0:T1:L0'
>>>
```